# Pig Version Mismatch (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Did anyone has met the problem before? This is error log:

Protocol org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobSubmissionProtocol version mismatch. (client = 20, server = 21)

I used pig 0.8.0 and my hadoop version is 0.20.10.

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think Pig 0.8.0 is bundled with Hadoop 0.20.2 and even a minor version difference matters.

So for example you could recompile your Pig with your Hadoop 0.20.10 in order to have the same Hadoop version in both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tied to 0.8.1 ? If not you could download a newer version of Pig (0.10.0 works with 1.0.2) which comes with two jars (one with hadoop bundled, one without), and the pig script will utilize your installed client libraries if you set the HADOOP_HOME env variable before running pig